Resolution of the Convolution / Inverse Convolution in Python
The discrete convolution is defined as:
Discrete convoltuion
Both Scipy and Numpy packages have a function for convolution and Scipy has one for the inverse convolution. However, in all three cases, there isn't a parameter for defining the convolution resolution, i.e. "m" in the picture.
Is there a way to define this resolution, or any other suitable function?

Note that convolution operations are not (completely) invertible. Information is lost in the process and cannot be retrieved back. Machine learning solutions used to inverse the operation on picture seems often quite convincing but they actually create information which looks probable based on a large set of existing images (and so often not so far from the initial image). An example of that is large Gaussian blur. A way to compute it is to remove values in the FFT so (high) frequencies are lost forever.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Typically, for discrete convolution/inverse convolution, this isn't called resolution; it's called kernel size.
In cases where you're supplying the kernel, there is no need to also supply the kernel size. If you supply an array of size 2*M + 1, then the convolution/de-convolution knows how big M is.
